# Drools facts filtering with eval does not work for boolean with quotes ""

Tags: drools, jboss-eap-7, redhat-decision-manager

I have guided decision tables with a boolean condition column with predicate as follows

`"$param" == "NA"  ? true :  "$param" == boolFlag`

The decision table source translates as follows for different condition values  (true,false,NA)

For true

```
when
   f : Foo(..., eval( "true" == "NA"  ? true :  "true" == boolFlag ))
```

For false

```
when
   f : Foo(..., eval( "false" == "NA"  ? true :  "false" == boolFlag ))
```

For NA

```
when
   f : Foo(..., eval( "NA" == "NA"  ? true :  "NA" == boolFlag ))
```

These filters works on other environments (RHDM 7.52.0.Final-redhat-00008)  but when i try in my local, which is "RHDM 7.59.0.Final-redhat-00009"  it does not work anymore.

In my local, I transform the decision table to a drl file and I have to remove the quote "" from expression to work

```
when
   f : Foo(..., eval( "true" == "NA"  ? true :  true == boolFlag ))
```

It is only happening if eval() is used for fact filtering. If i remove the eval it also works with quotes like below

```
when
   f : Foo(..., "true" == boolFlag)
```

And if i use eval() outside of fact filtering, it works also

```
when
   eval("true" == boolFlag)
```

It does not work only if eval() is used for the fact filtering.
I am not sure it is due to the version difference or i need to change some config to make it work or not.

I am new to the drools and appreciate for any guide to finding the root cause.

---

My sample codes from local are as follows

```
package com.myspace.test;

rule "init"
    salience 100
    dialect "mvel"
    
    when
         eval(true)
    then
       drools.setFocus("AG1");
end

rule "test"
    salience 99
    agenda-group "AG1"
    activation-group "AVG1"
    dialect "mvel"
    
    when
        //      f : Foo(eval("true" == "NA" ? true :  "true" == copy))   // does not work in local  
        //      f : Foo(eval("true" == "NA" ? true :  true == copy))     // works in local
    //  f : Foo("true" == copy)                                  // works in local 
        eval("true" == true)          // works in local
        f : Foo()                               
    
       then
       System.out.println("Name = " + f.Name);
       
       //copy name to Bar
       Bar b = new Bar();
       b.setName(f.Name);
       insert(b);
end
```

Objects

```
package com.myspace.test;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class Foo implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label("Name")
    private java.lang.String name;
    @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label(value = "Copy")
    private boolean copy;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isCopy() {
        return this.copy;
    }

    public void setCopy(boolean copy) {
        this.copy = copy;
    }

    public Foo(java.lang.String name, boolean copy) {
        this.name = name;
        this.copy = copy;
    }

}
```

```
package com.myspace.test;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class Bar implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private java.lang.String name;

    public Bar() {
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Bar(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval`, it's extremely non-performant. The easiest solution is to make two different rules and omit the eval.

Comment: Those eval statements  are auto generated as source for decision tables by drools. Looks like need to transform decision tables to drl files or change the predicate to remove eval.  Thanks